# Is $\Gamma L(r,q^t)$ a subgroup of $\Gamma L(rt,q)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I know that $GL(r,q^t)$ can be seen as a subgroup of $GL(rt,q)$ since every linear transformation on the vector space $V(r,q^t)$ extends in a unique way to a linear transformation on the vector space $V(rt,q)$.

For $\Gamma L(r,q^t)$ however, I run into trouble if I want to embed the group in $\Gamma L(rt,q)$ in a direct way because several semilinear mappings on $V(r,q^t)$ correspond to the same semilinear mapping on $V(rt,q)$, several elements of $Aut(F_{q^t})$ have the same restriction to $F_q$.

Is there a way of embedding $\Gamma L(r,q^t)$ in $\Gamma L(rt,q)$? Or is this just not (always) possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer must be yes, although I can only show this indirectly, and I cannot see how to construct a canonical embedding - perhaps there isn't one!

If $q=p^e$ with $p$ prime, then we have embeddings $A \to B \to C$ with
$A={\rm GL}(r,q^t)$, $B={\rm GL}(rt,q)$, $C= {\rm GL}(rte,p)$, which are essentially unique (i.e. images of any two such embeddings are conjugate).

The normalizers in $C$ of $A$ and $B$ are respectively ${\rm \Gamma L}(r,q^t)$ and ${\rm \Gamma L}(rt,q)$, whereas the normalizer of $A$ in $B$ is the extension of $A$ by a field automorphism  of order $t$, induced by the map $x \mapsto x^q$ of the field of order $q^t$.

By the uniqueness of the embedding $A \to B$, we have $|N_{N_C(B)}(A)| = |N_B(A)| \times |N_C(B):B|$, which is equal to $|N_C(A)|$, so $N_C(A) < N_C(B)$, which is the required embedding.